# Huygens-Fresnel integral and Rayleigh integral

Tags: laser, diffraction, structural-beam, huygens-principle

[image]While working with the Huygens-Fresnel integral, I learned about the Rayleigh integral again, and I can't tell where they apply and whether they can be replaced equivalently. Also, in terms of structured light in a focusing system, which is better to use. Of course, I'd love to get some references!

Comment: To help your readers to answer your question please, spell out what you mean by the Huygens-Fresnel and Rayleigh integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Two excellent texts on this topic are the following: J. W. Goodman - Introduction to FOURIER OPTICS - McGraw - Hill. (It's quite old), Max Born and Emil Wolf - Principles of Optics - Cambridge (very old).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am sorry that I did not add the Rayleigh - Sommerfeld integral in cylindrical coordinates here because I saw multiple forms and could not be sure. Now I'm curious about their specific applications. I know something about it when I look up papers, but not much.